# pass id of foreign key to the form via post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, symfony4

I've created a new field ("responsavel") on my db for this entity ("Multa"), "responsavel" is a foreign key to another table (Usuario) and I want it to be shown on my form as an select with just some objects (that's why the `$desligados` I'm passing to the front) for the user to choose and then pass it to the back.

I've been able to do it with `$.post`but I'm doing other things after the submit is passed to the controller so I've included a `$(this).unbind('submit').submit();` but now it's like I'm submitting the form two times, and one of them is not submitting with the "responsavel" value.

This is my form:

```
class MultaType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('usuario')
            ->add('departamento')
            ->add('cliente')
            ->add('responsavel',null, ['attr'=>['style'=>'display:none;'], 'label'=> false])
            ->add('razaoSocial', null, ['label'=>'Cliente'])
            ->add('valor',null, ['label'=>'Valor Pago'])
            ->add('tipoPagamento', ChoiceType::class, ['choices'=>['Selecionar'=>0,'Integral'=>1,'Somente Encargos'=>2], 'required' => true], ['label' => 'Tipo de Pagamento'])
            ->add('dtRegistro', DateTimeType::class, ['widget'=>'single_text','input' => 'datetime','html5'=>false, 'label'=>'Data de Registro'])
            ->add('competencia', null, ['label'=>'Competência'])
            ->add('motivo', TextareaType::class, ['required'=>true])
            ->add('dtCiencia', DateTimeType::class, ['widget'=>'single_text','input' => 'datetime','html5'=>false, 'label'=>'Data de Ciência'])
            ->add('vistoCiencia', CheckboxType::class, ['label'=>'Ciente', 'required'=>false])
            ->add('nomeCliente', null, ['label'=>'Nome'])
            ->add('getRegistro', null, ['label'=>'CNPJ/CPF'])
            ->add('cpfCliente', null, ['label'=>'CPF'])
            ->add('cnpjCliente', null, ['label'=>'CNPJ'])

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Multa::class,
            'usuario' => Usuario::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

this is what I have on my controller:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/novo", name="multa_novo", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function novo(PushNotification $push,
        Request $request): Response
    {   
        $multa = new Multa();
        $form = $this->createForm(MultaType::class, $multa);
        $form->remove('usuario');
        $form->remove('departamento');
        $form->remove('dtCiencia');
        $form->remove('dtRegistro');
        $form->remove('razaoSocial');
        $form->remove('getRegistro');

        if(in_array($this->getUser()->getAcesso(), [1,2,3,4,7,10]))
        {
            $desligados = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Usuario::class)->findByAtivo(0);
        }
        else
        {
            $desligados = [];
        }
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $multa->setUsuario($this->getUser());
            $entityManager->persist($multa);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', "Multa registrada com sucesso!");
 
 - "HERE I HAVE OTHER THINGS I'M DOING AFTER THE SUBMIT..." -

            return $this->redirectToRoute('multa_index');
        }

        return $this->render('multa/novo.html.twig', [
            'entity' => $multa,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'coordenador' => $coordenador[0], //passando o primeiro objeto usuario encontrado para o front
            'desligados' => $desligados
        ]);
    }
```

what I'm doing on the front:

```
            {% if desligados %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 mb-3" data-intro="Nome do coordenador responsável pela ciência da multa." data-step="5">
              <label>Responsável  <i class=" ml-1 text-info icon-sm mdi mdi-information-outline" title="Caso o responsável pela multa ja tenha sido desligado." data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"></i></label>
              <select id="responsavel" name="multa[responsavel]" class="form-control">
                  <option></option>
                {% for responsavel in desligados %}
                  <option value="{{responsavel.id}}">{{ responsavel.nomeCompleto }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
            {% else %}

...


 $(function () {
      $("#multaForm").submit(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var form = $("#multaForm").serializeObject(); //Envia todo o formuário
        form['multa[responsavel]'] = $('#responsavel').val();

        $.post( {% if __rota[1] == 'novo' %} "{{ path('multa_novo') }}" {% elseif __rota[1] == 'editar' %} "{{ path('multa_editar', {'id': entity.id } ) }}" {% else %} "{{ path('multa_aprovacao', {'id': entity.id } ) }}" {% endif %}, form, function( data ) {
        }).fail(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
        $(this).unbind('submit').submit();
        });
  });
```

A example of one submit on my db: [image]

Comment: use EntityType with a custom query_builder option provided by the controller to the form.

Comment: daamn! something so simple and I didn't knew about it. THANK YOU SO MUCH man!

Comment: A bit offtopic but `.unbind()` has been deprecated for a long time, it's been replaced by [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: @LucasMarques you're welcome. Please feel free to write up an answer to your question and mark it as the solution, to help others that come after you ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jakumi recommended I used the EntityType::class to create a custom querybuilder, it returned what i wanted and as I'm using the formType to render all the fields I didn't needed to do anything on the frontend to pass it to my controller.

[image]